# How to wrap words with anchor tags in react if string contains certain symbols

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, web

Hey guys am working on blog content with #hashtags and @mentions,i want a to check for all the words in a string if this words have @mention or #tags wrap them with anchor tags, so incase i have something like "hello @watchdog are you with @example and #trends #football"

so i want to wrap to have something like [@watchdog](/watchdog) [@exmaple](/emaple) [#exmaple](/trend)

am using react js

```
export const text = (text) =>{
const [linktext,setLinkText] =  useState('')

useEffect(()=>{
},[])

return (
   <div>{text}</div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const text = (text) =>{
const [linktext,setLinkText] =  useState("hello @watchdog are you with @example and #trends #football")

useEffect(()=>{
},[])

return (
   <div>{linktext.split(" ").map(word => (
         (word.includes("@") || word.includes("#"))
           ?
         <a>{word} </a>
        :
        <p>{word}</p>
    ))}</div>
)
}
```

Comment: i am having a TypeError word.contains is not a function

Comment: replace with includes. Check the updated answer

Comment: words.includes worked but all the words are joint together
hello@watchdogareyouwith@exampleand#trends#football

Comment: just give space after the {word} or use &nbsp; before the closing tag

Comment: thanks alot it woked for be but my href seems to have the https://@watchdog any idea how to fix it to https://watchdog or from  https://#trend  to https://trend

Comment: Do you want to give any url to that ?

Comment: I you want to give any kind of url or reference to that just use like <a href={}>{word}</a>... Inside the empty curl braces you could fill any thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242877/discussion-between-watch-dog-and-dinesh-oz).